# Calling variables from other functions

Tags: python, function

Is there any easy way to call a variable from one function to the other?
I am trying to make conversion program for distance/time/speed the output is supposed to look like this:

```
1 Enter the distance [m]: 400
2 Enter the time [min]: 0.7197
3
4 Original distance: 400 m
5 = 0.2486 mi
6 = 437.6 yd
7 = 1312.4 ft
8 = 15748.0 in
9
10 Your distance and time give speeds of:
11 9.26 m/s, 10.13 yd/s, 33.35 km/hr, and 20.73 mi/hr.
```

What I have so far is this:

```
def getInput():
    dist=int(input("Enter the distance [m]: "))
    time=input("Enter the time [min]: ")
    convDist(dist,time)

def convDist(dist,time):
    miles=dist*.0006214
    yards=dist*1.094
    feet=dist*3.281
    inches=dist*39.37
    km=dist*.001
    print("Original distance: ",dist)
    print("= ",miles," mi")
    print("= ",yards," yd")
    print("= ",feet," ft")
    print("= ",inches," in")
    print()
    convTime(time)


def convTime(time):
    time=float(time)
    seconds=time*60
    hours=time/60
    calcSpeed(hours,seconds)

def calcSpeed(hours,seconds):
    ms=dist/seconds
    yds=yards/seconds
    kmhr=km/hours
    mihr=miles/hours
    print("Your distance and time give speeds of:\n"
    ,m,"m/s",yds,"yd/s",kmhr,"km/hr",mihr,"mi/hr")


def main():
    getInput()

main()
```

Where I am having problems is getting numbers(inputs) from the first function to the calcSpeed() function where I need that input to calculate the speed.

Comment: Add them to the lambda list ( the list of parameters )

Comment: you don't appear to ever be returning anything... have the methods return a value?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values you need to the function. If the values are calculated by an intermediate function then `return` them.

Your functions `convTime` and `convDist` can be re-written so that they have a `return` statement and they return the stuff you would like to be made available outside the function in an appropriate form.

Example

```
def convTime(time):
    time=float(time)
    seconds=time*60
    hours=time/60
    return {'time':time,'seconds':seconds,'hours':hours}
```

And then in your calling function

```
time_dict = convTime(time)
calcSpeed(dist,time_dict)
```

You will have to change your `calcSpeed` function accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting a function inside another function, but you can just calculate values inside a function and take them out using `return` statement.

```
def getInput():
    dist=int(input("Enter the distance [m]: "))
    time=input("Enter the time [min]: ")

    return dist, time
```

Then use the values returned from one function for the next function.

```
dist,time = getInput()
miles,yards,feet,inches,km = convDist(dist,time)
```

and so on...

Comment: Wouldn't this cause it to reprompt for the dist and time if I called for it?